# Programatically retrieve count of javascript errors on page

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, selenium

I'd like to write a test case (using Selenium, but not the point of this question) to validate that my web application has no script errors\warnings or unhanded exceptions at certain points in time (like after initializing a major library).

This information can easily be seen in the debug consoles of most browsers. Is it possible to execute a javascript statement to get this information programatically?

It's okay if it's different for each browser, I can deal with that.

Comment: considering the javascript interpreter ceases to interpret when it encounters an error, i don't think this is possible.

Comment: That is not true at all. When a runtime error occurs in a javascript, the currently executing function returns at that point with an undefined result - which can cause an immediate functional error or more insidiously poison later code. On IE 6\7\8 it might show a dialog to the user, depending on the browser options. In Chorme, Safari and other good browsers, its a more silent process. Regardless, it's something you probably want to test for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not so far read about your issue (as far as I understood your problem)  [here](http://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2010/6/7/Checking-for-JavaScript-Errors-with-Selenium)

The idea be the following:
*I found, however, that I was often getting JavaScript errors when the page first loaded (because I was working on the JS and was introducing errors), so I was looking for a quick way to add an assert to my test to check whether any JS errors occurred. After some Googling I came to the conclusion that there is nothing built into Selenium to support this, but there are a number of hacks that can be used to accomplish it. I'm going to describe one of them here. Let me state again, for the record, that this is pretty hacky. I'd love to hear from others who may have better solutions.
I simply add a script to my page that will catch any JS errors by intercepting the **window.onerror** event:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onerror=function(msg){
        $("body").attr("JSError",msg);
    }
</script>
```

*This will cause an attribute called JSError with a value corresponding to the JavaScript error message to be added to the body tag of my document if a JavaScript error occurs. Note that I'm using jQuery to do this, so this specific example won't work if jQuery fails to load. Then, in my Selenium test, I just use the command `assertElementNotPresent` with a target of `//body[@JSError]`. Now, if any JavaScript errors occur on the page my test will fail and I'll know I have to address them first. If, for some strange reason, I want to check for a particular JavaScript error, I could use the assertElementPresent command with a target of `//body[@JSError='the error message']`.*

Hope this fresh idea helps you :)

Comment: You could have just answered by pointing to this link - http://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2010/6/7/Checking-for-JavaScript-Errors-with-Selenium

Comment: Had no idea about this event. Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
    //code
} catch(exception) {
    //send ajax request: exception.message, exception.stack, etc.
}
```

More info - [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)